# How to include value of a div in an img src in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

There is a value within a div. This value is not stored in a div but was actually coming from an html table which I extract using this syntax :

```
$('table#showalluporders tbody tr').click(function() {
  var tableData = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  $('#txtono').val($.trim(tableData[0]));       /* Order No */
  **$('#txtdiv').text($.trim(tableData[4]));**  /* File Name */
});
```

Syntax of div in which the value **#txtdiv** is showing :

```
<div id="txtdiv"></div>
```

Now, the problem is - I want to put value of div in a PHP variable so that it can be included in the image src:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/savelabel/<?php $imgval ?>" alt=""/>
```

How can I achieve this? As required here is my code :

```
<div class="bx1">
  <div id="txtdiv"></div>
</div>
<script>
  var link_base = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url').'/savelabel/'; ?>" ;
  var img_name = $('#txtdiv').html();
  $('#imgid').attr('src', link_base + img_name);
</script>
<div class="bx2">
  <img id="imgid" src="" alt="" class="imgsty" />   
</div>
<div class="bx3">
  <label class="lblsty">Order No.</label>
  <label class="colonsty">:</label>
  <input id="txtono" type="text" name="txtono" value="" readonly class="txtosty" /><br /><br />
</div>  
<div style="float:left; width:100%; height:10pt"></div>

<!-- Table 1 -->
<?php
  $selquery = "SELECT t_ordid, file_name FROM utmp_orders;
?>
<div class="t1cls">Order No.</div>

<div id="tabstatbox1" class="scroll">
  <table id="showalluporders">
    <thead><tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr></thead>    
      <?php 
       if (empty($retrv)){ 
         die("No Record Found." . mysqli_error($connection)); 
        }
        else {  
      while($retrvarr1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retrv)){ 
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $retrvarr1["t_ordid"]; ?></td>
              <td id="blocksty"><?php echo $retrvarr1["file_name"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
    <?php }} ?>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $('table#showalluporders tbody tr').click(function() {
        var tableData = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
        $('#txtono').val($.trim(tableData[0]));     /* Order No */
    $('#txtdiv').text($.trim(tableData[4]));    /* File Name */
     });
  </script>
</div>
```

Layout of my screen is somewhat like this.

**Block 1**

[ img1.jpg ]  <-- div id="txtdiv"

---

< Image Block >             Order No. : [  1   ]

### **Block 2**

### Order No.--------Order Date------------ Status

```
1--------------15-2-2015---------------Paid
2--------------15-2-2015---------------Paid
3--------------15-2-2015---------------Paid
4--------------15-2-2015---------------Paid
```

**Block 3**
 Submit - Button

Scenario: when the user clicks a row of "Block 2 Table" file name of the image in other hidden column will be shown in "Block1 div" and from there through code image will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a three step process.

First, save your `base url` as a JS variable:

```
var link_base = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url').'/savelabel/'; ?>" ;
```

Next, retrieve the value from the `div`:

```
var img_name = $('#txtdiv').html();
```

Last, put all that into the `src`:

```
$('#your_img_id').attr('src', link_base + img_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's still not working.                                                              <img id="imgid" src alt="" class="imgsty" /> .Using Inspect element src is showing blank. Please help

Comment: is there any one who can help me please.